# i need some help about the login system

Tags: java

I write a code about the login system. It has user and admin. About the user, they can change their password. The account for the user is already in a txt file and when the user changes the password, the new password has to be written in that txt file and keep other users in txt file. The problem is when I click change password its write a new password with the username but in txt file still has the old password of the user that want to change the password.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class TEST4
        {
            public static Scanner S;
            public static Scanner H;
            private JFrame Frame;

            private JPanel Panel;

            private JButton Button;
            private JButton Button1;

            private JLabel Label1;
            private JLabel Label;
            private JLabel Label3;
            private JLabel Label4;
            JTextField txt = new JTextField("",50);
            JTextField txt1 = new JTextField("",50);

            public static void main(String[] args)
                {

                System.out.println("Loading...");

                new TEST4 ();
                }
            public TEST4 ()
                {
                Application();
                }
            public void Application()
                {
                Frame = new JFrame("Welcome");
                Frame.setVisible(true);

                Frame.setSize(400,400);
                Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                Panel = new JPanel();
                //Panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                Panel.setLayout(null);//Override auto arrange elements

                txt1.setBounds(80, 50, 100, 25);
                txt.setBounds(80, 10, 100, 25);

                Button = new JButton("Sign in");
                Button.setBounds(80, 90, 100, 25);//(x,y,w,h)
                Label = new JLabel("username : ");
                Label.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 25);
                Label1 = new JLabel("password : ");
                Label1.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 25);

                Panel.add(Button);
                Panel.add(Label);
                Panel.add(Label1);

                Panel.add(txt);
                Panel.add(txt1);
                Frame.add(Panel);
                Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                    {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                        String X=txt.getText();
                        String X1=txt1.getText();
                        String filepath="username.txt";

                        Search(X,X1,filepath);  
                        Frame.setVisible(false);            
                                JFrame Frame2 = new JFrame("User Setting");
                                Frame2.setVisible(true);

                                Frame2.setSize(400,400);
                                Frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel(); 
                                Panel2.setLayout(null);
                                Label3= new JLabel("Welcome user");
                                Label3.setBounds(5, 10, 100, 25);
                                JTextField txt3 = new JTextField("",50);
                                txt3.setBounds(80,50,100,25);
                                Button1= new JButton("Change password");
                                Button1.setBounds(180, 60, 100, 25);
                                Button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                    {
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b)
                                    {
                                    String X2=txt3.getText();
                                    String user="";
                                    String pass="";
                                    boolean found=false;

                                    try
                                    {
                                    H= new Scanner(new File(filepath));
                                    H.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

                                    while (H.hasNext() && !found)
                                        {
                                            user=H.next();
                                            pass=H.next();
                                            FileWriter H=new FileWriter("username.txt",true);

                                            H.close();
                                        if(user.trim().equals(X.trim()) && pass.trim().equals(X1.trim()))
                                            {
                                            FileWriter J = new FileWriter("username.txt",true);
                                            J.write("\r\n");
                                            J.write(X+","+X2);
                                            J.write("\r\n");




                                            J.close();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        H.close();


                                    }
                                    catch(Exception h)
                                    {
                                    System.out .print("error");                         
                                    }
                                    }
                                    });
                                    Panel2.add(Label3);
                                    Panel2.add(txt3);
                                    Panel2.add(Button1);    
                                    Frame2.add(Panel2);     
                                if(X.equals("tan123") && X1.equals("123456"))
                            {
                                Frame.setVisible(false);
                                Frame2.setVisible(false);
                                JFrame Frame3= new JFrame("Admin setting");
                                Frame3.setVisible(true);
                                Frame3.setSize(400,400);
                                Frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                JPanel Panel3 = new JPanel(); 
                                Panel3.setLayout(null);
                                Label4= new JLabel("Welcome admin");
                                Label4.setBounds(5, 10, 100, 25);
                                JTextField txt4 = new JTextField("",50);
                                txt4.setBounds(80,50,100,25);
                                    Panel3.add(Label4);
                                    Panel3.add(txt4);

                                    Frame3.add(Panel3);
                            }


                        }   




                        });

                }
            public static void Search(String X,String X1,String filepath)
                {
                    boolean found=false;
                    String username="";
                    String password="";
                try
                {

                    S=new Scanner (new File(filepath));
                    S.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

                    while (S.hasNext() && !found)
                    {
                        username=S.next();
                        password=S.next();
                    if(username.trim().equals(X.trim()) && password.trim().equals(X1.trim()))
                        {
                        found=true;
                        }

                    }

                    S.close();

                    if(found==true)
                        {
                        System.out.print("welcome");
                        }

                    else
                        {
                        System.out.print("invalid");
                        }
                }
                catch(Exception a)
                {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }


    }
    }
```

im a new guy to this so its still a mess.

this the old txt file that has old username and password

```
tan,123

shay,098
```

and when i change password for user tan into 456 and its like this

```
tan,123

shay,098tan,456
```

How can I delete the `tan,123` and replace that with `tan,456` and still keep `shay,098`.
Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If the problem is about reading from a file and writing back to the file, we don't need to see any of your UI code. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem and what you have tried so far to solve it, and why that didn't work.

Comment: Incidentally, just a heads-up: Never-ever-ever store a password in clear text. Just don't do it. Really. Trust me. At the very least, look into salted hashing.

Comment: And in addition to the comments above, use more appropriate variable names than `X`, `H`, `J` etc.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to store data in text files and instead it would be wise to store them as records in databases or CSV(which is a text file to begin with). Regardless, an easy solution for your problem is to read the whole data from the text file and replace the appropriate text/password using StringBuffer or similar classes and then write down the whole string to the file.